# Typescript: Using new in namespace

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working on creating DefinitelyTyped for the private package (I cannot change source code) and I cannot find any way to implement type like this:

```
  GlobalNameSpace.SuperClass = function(arg) {}
  GlobalNameSpace.superClass = new GlobalNameSpace.SuperClass(args)
```

My attempt:

```
declare namespace GlobalNameSpace {
    class SuperClass {}

    const superClass = new GlobalNameSpace.SuperClass(args);
}
```

Sadly when I do it I have error in VS Code.

```
A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference.
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the help from @elderapo on https://discord.gg/typescript

Final solution:

```
declare namespace GlobalNamespace {
    class SuperKomp {
        constructor();
        public on(key: string): void;
    }

    const komp: GlobalNamespace.SuperKomp;
}

GlobalNamespace.komp.on('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
declare namespace GlobalNameSpace {
    export class SuperClass { }
    export const superClass: typeof SuperClass;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not solve my problem. When you do `GlobalNameSpace.superClass.sth ` there is an error on `sth`. 
My code http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=24#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCDiEA9gEZQQByqG2u8A3gFACQkU668AygK6YgwBpQikz1mLQonQAXGNzDTCMABQBKANzjM3YhACWYeJOUBrEAE8AXPBkw9iAOarrAN0J7gmpgF8GzMJIy8CbCmNbS5nyEAGbwBCRklGhYOCAAdDx8gqGavgzxpBRUKbhpISJpkkA